# Splitting columns of a dataframe to merge a repetitive variable

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I normally find an answer in previous questions posted here, but I can't seem to find this one, so here is my maiden question:

I have a dataframe with one column with repetitive values, I would like to split the other columns and have only 1 value in the first column and more columns than in the original dataframe.

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(test = c(rep(1:5,3)), time = sample(1:100,15), score = sample(1:500,15))
```

The original dataframe has 3 columns and 15 rows.

And it would turn into a dataframe with 5 rows and the columns would be split into 7 columns: 'test', 'time1', 'time2', 'time3', 'score1', score2', 'score3'.

Does anyone have an idea how this could be done?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Please add the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it

Comment: I tried my best, but I don't know how to copy/paste (desired) output into the question. Thanks for the welcome, I read through the help center, I'm sorry if my question was below par. I will read through it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using `dcast` with `rowid` from the data.table-package is well suited for this task:

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), test ~ rowid(test), value.var = c('time','score'), sep = '')
```

The result:

```
   test time1 time2 time3 score1 score2 score3
1:    1    52     3    29     21    131     45
2:    2    79    44     6    119      1    186
3:    3    67    95    39     18    459    121
4:    4    83    50    40    493    466    497
5:    5    46    14     4    465      9     24
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
df <- data.frame(test = c(rep(1:5,3)), time = sample(1:100,15), score = sample(1:500,15))

df$class <- c(rep('a', 5), rep('b', 5), rep('c', 5))


df <- split(x = df, f = df$class)

binded <- cbind(df[[1]], df[[2]], df[[3]])

binded <- binded[,-c(5,9)]


> binded
  test time score class time.1 score.1 class.1 time.2 score.2 class.2
1    1   40   404     a     57     409       b     70      32       c
2    2    5   119     a     32     336       b     93     177       c
3    3   20   345     a     44      91       b    100      42       c
4    4   47   468     a     60     265       b     24     478       c
5    5   16    52     a     38     219       b      3      92       c
```

Let me know if it works for you!

Comment: You can change this `binded <- cbind(df[[1]], df[[2]], df[[3]])` to`binded =do.call(cbind,df)`

Comment: That is correct! Thank's for the tip! I think that I must use `do.call` more often!

Comment: Ingenious solution, and thanks for replying so fast. But I think h3rm4n's solution is a bit cleaner for this specific problem.